# Combinatorics. How many 5 digit numbers that don't divide by 5?

Tags: combinatorics

Good evening everyone. I'm trying to solve this math problem. How many 5 digit numbers can we create using only these numbers $(0; 3; 6; 7; 8)$. Created numbers cannot be divided by $5$ and the given numbers (the ones that we use to create the 5 digit number) can't repeat.

I know that correct answer is $72$, but I'm not sure how to get it. Maybe someone could help me with that? Thank you in advance

Comment: In order for a number to be divisible by $5$, it needs to have a units digit of $0$ or $5$.

Comment: There are $120$ permutations in total, and if a number has $0$ as the last digit, it is divisible by $5$. Hence $24$ of them are divisible by $5$. Hence I believe that the correct answer should be $96$ not $72$.

Comment: first digit cant be $0$ either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $4$ ways to select the first digit (it cant be $0$).

After this there are $3$ ways to select the last digit (it cant be $0$ either).

After this there are $3!$ ways to select the numbers in the middle.

So the answer is $4\times 3\times 6=72$

---

Alternative solution:

Place the digit $0$ in any of $3$ positions and the rest in $4!$ ways.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to arrange $5$ digits total is $5! = 120$

We need to consider 2 other cases to meet the criteria for the question

Considering $0$ as the first digit:
the number of ways to arrange $4$ digits total is $4!=24$

Considering $0$ as the last digit:
the number of ways to arrange $4$ digits total is $4!=24$

We take the total number of combinations and subtract that combinations that are not allowed, so the total then becomes:
$5! - 4! - 4! = 120 - 24 - 24 = 72$